# SharePoint 2013 - Render Page in iFrame without Navigation Elements?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iframe, global-navigation

I'm in a SP environment that is tightly controlled and for instance don't have access to Designer.

I'm attempting to setup a page to have the user select contents from buttons, which will then load those 'content' pages into an iFrame.  I have a test case setup and working.  However, when I click a button and a page loads within the iFrame it brings with it the global navigation and left menu bar.  I've tried:

1) Appending ?Dlg=1 to the URLs.  No change.

2) Applying following code to the

```
<style type="text/css">

    #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}

    .s4-ca{margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}

</style>
```

3) Applying following code through CWEP, but SP keeps overwriting it.

```
<style>
.ms-core-navigation { DISPLAY: none }
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your #1 should work but you have to use the correct querystring.

Instead of `?Dlg=1` it should be `?isDlg=1`.

Answer (score -1):

`?Dlg=1` is wrong.

You must use `?isDlg=1`.

Answer (score -1):

First Add script editor web part and then add style in script editor.